# Wrapper restart on out of memory

Tags: java, java-service-wrapper

I need to configure wrapper file for restart the wrapper when the Heap memory space is occurred. I have done something from what I learned through net. But still the OutOfMemory persists. Here my configuration file.

```
wrapper.java.command=./jre/bin/java.exe
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp

wrapper.java.classpath.1=./lib/wrapper.jar    
wrapper.java.classpath.2=./automatictester.jar

wrapper.java.library.path.1=./lib
wrapper.java.additional.1=

wrapper.java.initmemory=5
wrapper.java.maxmemory=64

wrapper.app.parameter.1= sample.automatic
wrapper.console.format=PM

wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile=./logs/wrapper.log

wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

wrapper.logfile.maxsize=1m
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=2

wrapper.syslog.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.console.title=Sample Application for Testing

wrapper.ntservice.name=Automatic Tester
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=Automatic Tester

wrapper.ntservice.description=Automatic Tester 
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

wrapper.ntservice.starttype=DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false

wrapper.filter.trigger.1=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.action.1=RESTART

#wrapper.java.monitor.heap.threshold.percent=99 
#wrapper.java.monitor.heap.restart=true
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Fixing the outOfMemoryError is not an option?

Comment: I want to restart the wrapper if the OutOfMemory occurred

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need the following property set:

```
wrapper.filter.trigger.1=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.action.1=RESTART
```

for more information, please take a look at the following page:

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-filter-x-n.html#outofmemory

cheers,